# Select rows with date range within another date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of accounts that has columns for start date and end date. I want the user to supply a start date and end date and all data must be returned where the account was active at any time between the user specified start date and end date.

The catch is that the end date may be null if the account is still currently active.

The account must be selected if it was open at any time between the user specified range which means that even accounts that were opened or closed between the range must be included.

Here is a picture of what I want.

[image]

The yellow part is the date range entered by the user. The green parts is what I want selected. The light red part is what I don't want selected. The arrows on the end of G, H and I mean that those accounts don't have an end date. All other ones that don't have an arrow have an end date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, this amounts to checking that the account start date is prior to the user supplied end date and the account end date is after the user supplied start date (or is null, in which case we don't even need to check it):

```
where
    account.start_date < @user_end_date and
    (account.end_date >= @user_start_date or account.end_date is null)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    accounts
WHERE
    (start_date >= :user_supplied_start AND start_date <= :user_supplied_end)
OR
    (end_date >= :user_supplied_end AND end_date <= :user_supplied_start)
OR
    (start_date <= :user_supplied_start AND end_date IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    accounts
WHERE   start_date <= @input_end_date
        AND (end_date >= @input_start_date OR (end_date IS NULL AND NOW() >= @input_start_date))
```